# axios/react post request : no parameter sent to backend (flask api)

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

Dears,
have an issue. When posting an axios request to flask server with a parameter, the parameter is not received by flask.

Axios : 0.18
React : 16.3.2
Redux : 4

Here is code where the issue is located:

```
confirm: token =>
      axios
          .post("/api/auth/confirmation", { token })
          .then(res => res.data.user),
```

the variable token is not empty. Even if replace it by a fix value (e.g 2323232), I get a 405 response form API

```
  axios
      .post("/api/auth/confirmation", "2323232")
      .then(res => res.data.user),
```

the flask servers responds status 405, because in fact it receives the url, but not the value of the parameter:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2018 16:21:14] "POST /api/auth/confirmation HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

But if the value is included in the URL, then there is no issue:

```
  axios
      .post("/api/auth/confirmation/2323232")
      .then(res => res.data.user),
```

result is fine :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2018 16:04:01] "POST /api/auth/confirmation/2323232 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

thks & Rgds

Ps : flask backend code is very simple:

```
@app.route('/api/auth/confirmation/<token>',methods=['POST'])
def confirmation(token):
    return jsonify({'user':'ok'}),200
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
@app.route('/api/auth/confirmation/<token>',methods=['POST'])
```

you should use something like:

```
from flask import request 

@app.route('/api/auth/confirmation/',methods=['POST'])
def confirmation():
    token = request.get_json()['token']
    # ... rest of code ...
```

[More info](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object)

Comment: get an other error : "Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

have change the code this way :
@app.route('/api/auth/confirmation/',methods=['POST'])
def confirmation():
    token = request.form['token']

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: but in fact I had to use request.get_json()

Thks

Comment: You welcome, please remember to mark as answer if it helped :)